# How do I modify GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter to operate over a rectangle Focus (eg. instagram) instead of a circle Focus to move blurred area?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

If we call method handle pan or handle tap method from `GPUImage` it displays focused part in circle but i want to change it in square focus so is it possible to change ?

I did RND on it but i cannot find anything so please help me.